# Bootstrap affix using data-attributes only works on page reload

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, turbolinks

I am working on a Rails4 application using bootstrap affix functionality via data-attributes.

I am using the data-attributes like this:

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="300" data-offset-bottom="615">
...stuff...
...stuff...
...stuff...
</div>
```

My only CSS for the affix classes is the following:

```
.affix {
    width: 255px;
    margin-top: -300px;
}

.affix-bottom {
    position: relative;
}

.affix-top {
    position: relative;
}
```

Everything works perfectly when I reload the page, except that it does not work when I navigate to it initially from another page on my web application.

Seems other people has trouble with this and its a turbolinks issue. Tried all their approaches but nothing worked:
tried using jquery-turbolinks nothing
so i just ended up removing turbolinks all together.. Would rather use turbolinks if I can get this to work if someone knows a way I can do it.
Any ideas about why this can be happening?

Comment: This is possibly due to Turbolinks: this GEM may help [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed turbolinks to make this work. Could not find a way to make this work with Turbolinks.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing the data attributes and initializing the affix after page had loaded (i use [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)), like so:

```
  $(document).ready ->
    $('#myAffix').affix({
      offset:
        top: 100,
        bottom: 0
    })
```

(Excuse my coffeescript!)

If you need to set offset etc with dataattributes (i.e. you have different offsets for each affix on you site). You can just create your own data attributes and get them using `$('#myAffix').data('offset-top')` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the top property for .affix element in your CSS. Negative margin might cause problem in affix offset calculation -

```
.affix{
   top: 300px; /* Set the top position of pinned element */
}
```

Check this URL, may be it will be helpful to you - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-affix.php